# Firefox XULRunner or TriXul?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, xulrunner

This problem is exercising our minds very much at the moment.

XULRunner https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner
Trixul Cross-Platform GUI Toolkit http://www.trixul.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a commerical project, it seems like XULRunner is the obvious choice since it is the much more mature platform.

Answer (score 0):

XULRunner is complex.

How about [QT](http://qt.nokia.com), or [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org)? Both are cross platform, QT is easy to learn, check out [this PDF e-book](http://www.qtrac.eu/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.zip).